# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).hasClass(...).show is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

No idea why this isn't working but I'm hoping a second set of eyes.

Yes I'm referencing the jQuery library.

```
var $current_selection;
$('.nav-link').hide();

$('a').click(function () {

    current_selection = $(this).attr("class");

    $('#nav').find("div").hasClass(current_selection).show();

});
```

My HTML

```
<a href="#" class="link-one">Nav Option One</a>
<div id="nav">
    <div class="nav-link link-one">
        <p>Test Link One</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Error I'm getting in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).hasClass(...).show is not a
>   function

Comment: It might have helped someone else out. I'm really terrible at reading docs and absorbing information so something like this may seem simple but it helps some people out.

Comment: Upvote is for research effort too .. , a simple [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or debug would have highlight your problem, even if you did not read the docs

Comment: My example above is minimal compared to my actual code and I did attempt to debug but without the knowledge of `hasClass` returning boolean I was not resolving the right problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) returns boolean value, so you cannot chain `hasClass`.

You can use

```
$('#nav').find("div." + current_selection).show();
```

---

If `current_selection` contains multiple classes, the classes will contains spaces and the selector will not work as expected. To make it work, all the spaces need to be replaced by `.`.

```
current_selection = $(this).attr("class").replace(/ /g, '.');
$('#nav').find("div." + current_selection).show();
```

Answer (score 6):

`hasClass()` returns `true` or `false`. You'll want to actually *select* the appropriate elements:

```
 $("#nav div." + current_selection).show();
```

Comment: This of course only works if `current_selection` only contains a single class name (like in the example).

Comment: @FelixKling But then, so does `hasClass()`, so we haven't lost any of the *intended* functionality.

Comment: I guess. Though `$( "<div class='foo bar'></div>" ).hasClass( "foo bar" )` returns true, while `$( "<div class='foo bar baz'></div>" ).hasClass( "foo baz" )` returns false :-/ Either way, I'm less concerned about `hasClass`, and more about the fact that the `<a>`'s `class` attribute *could* contain multiple classes. Just something to keep in mind.